# How to Show Class Description, Attribute descriptions and Operation Descriptions of jmx MBeans

Tags: java, spring, jboss7.x, jmx, mbeans

I have created some beans that implement an interface and created a custom `MBean` exporter to expose those beans to `jconsole`.
Although everything works fine, the descriptions are not shown correctly.
At the top of the bean I see:

```
Java Class :   $Proxy483
Description :   Information on the management interface of the MBean
```

and at the descriptions of the attributes and the operations I see:

```
Operation exposed for management
```

Is there any way to see the descriptions I have set in `@ManagedResource` annotations?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a JmxAttributeSource implementation for your MBeanExporter (there is no default). Spring [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html#jmx-interface) provides the following example:

```
<bean id="exporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter">
    <property name="assembler" ref="assembler"/>
    <property name="namingStrategy" ref="namingStrategy"/>
    <property name="autodetect" value="true"/>
</bean>

<!-- Implementation of the JmxAttributeSource interface that reads JDK 1.5+ annotations and exposes the corresponding attributes -->
<bean id="jmxAttributeSource" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationJmxAttributeSource"/>

<!-- will create management interface using annotation metadata -->
<bean id="assembler" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler">
    <property name="attributeSource" ref="jmxAttributeSource"/>
</bean>

<!-- will pick up the ObjectName from the annotation -->
<bean id="namingStrategy" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.naming.MetadataNamingStrategy">
    <property name="attributeSource" ref="jmxAttributeSource"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to provide object name and description?

```
@ManagedResource(
    objectName="org.springbyexample.jmx:name=ServerManager", 
    description="Server manager."
)
```